# Rails collection_select + bootstrap dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<div class="dropdown">
...
 <%= ff.collection_select :vendor_id, @vendors, :id, :vendor, :include_blank => true, class: "dropdown-menu" %> 
...
</div>
```

I have a form and then I'm using fields_for as shown above to collect input. But I'm unable to see the stylized bootstrap dropdown as illustrated [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp). What changes should I be making to see the bootstrap stylized dropdown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from

```
<%= ff.collection_select :vendor_id, @vendors, :id, :vendor, :include_blank => true, class: "dropdown-menu" %>
```

to

```
<%= ff.collection_select :vendor_id, @vendors, :id, :vendor, {:include_blank => true}, {class: "dropdown-menu"} %>
```

collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})